# Left Join query returns duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have additives table:

```
id   name
30   gro
31   micro
32   bloom
33   test
```

And stage_additives table:

```
stage_id  additive_id   dose
195       30            2
195       31            3
195       32            1
```

Mysql query:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       sa.dose
FROM   additives a
LEFT JOIN stage_additives sa
ON     sa.stage_id = 195
```

Result is:

```
id name  dose
32 Bloom 2
32 Bloom 3
32 Bloom 1
30 Gro 2
30 Gro 3
30 Gro 1
31 Micro 2
31 Micro 3
31 Micro 1
33 test 2
33 test 3
33 test 1
```

This does not make sense to me as there ore 3 of each item in the result even though there is only one item per each table with same id/name.

I also tried inner join, right join but result is almost identical except for order.

What I want is all id, name from additives and dose from stage_additives if it exists otherwise NULL (or better still custom value of 0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the condition in your `left join`:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       sa.dose
FROM   additives a
LEFT JOIN stage_additives sa
ON     a.id = sa.additive_id and sa.stage_id = 195;
```

Remember, the `join` is conceptually doing a `cross join` between the two tables and taking only the rows that match the `on` condition (the `left join` is also keeping all the rows in the first table).  By not having an `on` condition, the join is keeping all pairs of rows from the two tables where `sa.stage_id = 195` -- and that is a lot of pairs.

EDIT:

(In response to moving the condition `sa.stage_id = 195` into a `where` clause.)

The condition `sa.stage_id = 195` is in the `on` clause on purpose.  This ensures that the `left join` actually behaves as written.  If the condition were moved to a `where` clause, then the `left join` would turn into an `inner join`.  Rows from `additive` with no match in `stage_additive` would have a `NULL` value for `sa.stage_id` and be filtered out.  I have to assume that the OP intended for the `left join` to keep all rows in `additive` because of the explicit use of `left join`.

Comment: Thats it! I am still confused why I am getting 3 identical items and not 2 or 4?

Comment: @DominicM . . . With the test data, I would expect you to get 4 output rows, one for each row in `additive`.  If you move the condition on `stage_id` to a `where` clause, then you will get 3 rows.

Comment: A `JOIN` is basically a *cross product* of tables. Say table `a` contains (1),(2) and table `b` contains (3),(4),(5) `a JOIN b` will produce a 6 rows result: (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3) (2,4) and (2,5). That *3 times* the value of the left table and *2 times* the values of the right table. Conceptually, the `ON` or `WHERE` clause just serve to *remove* unwanted results from that cross-product.

Answer (score 1):

in clause `ON` should be relation between tables and condition for stage_id in `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted something like

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       sa.dose
FROM   additives a
LEFT JOIN stage_additives sa 
          ON sa.additive_id = a.id
WHERE  sa.stage_id = 195
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd607/4

In this case, instead of a `LEFT JOIN` you can use an `INNER JOIN`, because the `WHERE` clause is based on the success of the join.

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       sa.dose
FROM   additives a
INNER JOIN stage_additives sa 
           ON sa.additive_id = a.id AND sa.stage_id = 195
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd607/8

But perhaps you really wanted a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       sa.dose
FROM   additives a
LEFT JOIN stage_additives sa
          ON sa.additive_id = a.id AND sa.stage_id = 195
```

This returns a fourth row:

```
33  test    (null)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd607/7

Comment: Gordon Linoff is correct in saying that condition should be in the ON clause and not WHERE since I want all rows from additives table regardless of stage_additives